# TableView inside custom tableviewcell - can't make smaller than full width?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a tableview inside a cell which sits left of a label. In the xib for the cell, the tableView appears positioned correctly, but when I run my app, it looks like it completely fills the cell and ignores other elements in the cell.

I've tried setting the bounds, changing the contentInset, and nothing seems to adjust the width so that the table doesn't bleed into elements and get cut off by elements right of it.

How can I make the tableview less than the full width of its containing cell?

[image]

Comment: How are you setting up your constraints? I tried this with a fixed size label pinned to the right side, and with a horizontal constraint to the inner table view (which had a fixed height and a constraint to the left side of the outer cell). This worked fine. On rotation, the inner table view expanded and the label stayed the same just as I expected.

Comment: I setup these constraints, and if I resize the cell within interface builder, it looks like the tableview width adjusts accordingly. But when I run the app, it's still as if the tableview consumes the full width of the cell.

Comment: ...never mind. I rebuilt the constraints on the inner cells, and now everything is good. It looks like the label flew off the container when the container (inner tableview) was resized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuild your constraints. Make sure that when your inner cells resize, their components layout correctly to the cell.